# Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ harmonic and $g(x):=tan(f(x))+e^{-|x|^2}$ bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

I am working on the following exercise:

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a harmonic function. Let further $g(x):=tan(f(x))+e^{-|x|^2}$ be bounded. Show that f is constant.

My approach:
To show the above, I want to use the liouville theorem for harmonic functions.
Since I know that $f$ is harmonic, I need to show that it is also bounded:
Since $g(x):=tan(f(x))+e^{-|x|^2}$ I can rewrite to $arctan(g(x)-e^{-|x|^2})=f(x)$. Because $arctan$ is bounded and equal to $f$ it follows that $f$ is bounded. Applying the liouville theorem shows that $f$ is constant.
Question: Is my approach correct?

Comment: Let $f$ be the nearest multiple of $\pi$. Then $g(x) $ is bounded as $x \to \infty$ but your arctan rearrangement fails to capture the unboundedness of $f$. The problem is that there isn't just a single branch of arctangent you can use to invert (even if $f$ is bounded you might need a large number of branches). More needs to be said when you want to "invert" using your hypotheses on $f$.

Comment: Instead, I would note $g$ is bounded iff $\tan(f(x))$ is bounded (adding the decaying exponential doesn't change things, just shifts up the bounding constant), which happens iff the image of $f$ avoids multiples of $\pi$. By continuity of $f$, this in particular implies $f(x) < \pi$ for all $x$ so $f$ is bounded so is constant (being harmonic).

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you very much!

Comment: Your statement that $f$ is bounded certainly does not suffice. You mean $|f|\le C< \pi/2$?